# Fix absolute urls in Flask apache application

Tags: python, apache, flask

I wrote a web application in Flask, then I decided to use Apache to deploy it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/flask-app/flask-app.py
    <Directory /var/www/flask-app>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But now, links such as:

```
<a href='/login'>Sign in</a>
```

Go to `/login` instead of `/app/login`. Is there any way to fix this, without changing all of the URLs?

Comment: a good reason to use [url_for()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for) in flask. those urls aren't landing into the flask app, so the redirect would be on apache in which case just run it from the root: `WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/...`. but if you use an IDE (e.g. PyCharm) they all have some support for project global find/replace...probably a pretty simple task to make them relative links.

Answer (score 1):

As [PJ Santoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6079732/pj-santoro) said you should be using [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for). This takes the ambiguity out of routes.

```
<a href='{{ url_for('route_function_name') }}'>Sign in</a>
```

Where:

```
@routes.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def route_function_name():
    return 'blah'
```